# Default parameter passing in C#

Tags: c#, parameters, parameter-passing, pass-by-value, reference-type

Maybe an old question, but am not finding anything comprehensive on the internet.

If the default parameter passing method in C# is [By value](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html), then how does it affect the initial Reference Type variable?

I.e. in the below example, why will it print "Hello World" instead of just "Hello", if it was parameter passing by value?

```
void Foo (StringBuilder x)
{
    x.Append (" World");
}   

StringBuilder y = new StringBuilder();
y.Append ("Hello");
Foo (y);
Console.WriteLine (y);
```

Comment: The reference to the string builder object is passed by value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything other than the primitive types (such as `int`, `byte` etc) are passed by reference by default. You are passing the same `StringBuilder` instance to the method.

Comment: They will be passed by reference but if they are immutable, there is no change on them. for example `string` is not primitive type, but there is no change in it's value.

Comment: -1: the reference is passed by value, furthermore, there are non-primitive value-types such as DateTime.

Comment: @canpoyrazoglu: Cool. Though I roughly understand, can you please define what are Primitive types?
And also, do you mean to say, all non-primitive types (Value or reference types) are passed by reference by default?

Comment: according to MSDN's own article, string is primitive http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711900%28VS.71%29.aspx (first result when I type primitive types in .net to google).
i know that the string instance is immutable in memory, but "to the user", it acts AS a primitive type. (DateTime is also primitive btw from the same perspective)

Comment: @Vishruth primitive types are the numeric types; integers and floating points. and types like string and datetime are also considered primitive in .net, in the sense that, if you pass them to a method, their value will be passed, and any changes you make to the passed values WON'T be reflected to the other (first) value at the other method. on the other hand, all the other types (as far as i remember) are references, where, when you pass them to a method, their "pointer" is copied, still "pointing to the same object in memory"

Comment: @canpoyrazoğlu Yes that was my mistake, but my point or Henrik point is that there are other types than what you said and they are value type, in fact we don't have primitive type / non primitive for separating way of their calling, these are sub class of general rule, Value Types and Reference Types, all structs are value type but not primitive ...

Comment: you are right, you are "technically" right against me, i was just trying to make things simpler to understand (people usually understand things better if they are taught in a way closer to "street language", in opposed to "professional" language, even though the explanation is imperfect too :))

Comment: I changed my above example to take a struct, which contained an int, string, string builder and a timespan members.
After calling the method foo, the initial struct member DID NOT change.

Comment: that's normal, `class`es are references and are passed by reference, `struct`s act like value types, they are allocated in the stack and when passing to a method, their value is copied. but any *references to class instances* INSIDE the struct will still be pointing to the same instance (such as stringbuilder)

Comment: To test the same thing, I added a string builder to my struct, but surprisingly, even the value of the string builder remained same (so was TimeSpan).
This test made me understand and get confused, both at the same time!

Comment: ok.. a pointer (a reference type's value, like, `StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder();` the `x` there) is like a debit card. you have a bank account and withdraw with that card. there is your bank account with money (the `StringBuilder` in memory location, say, 1234), and the debit card (`x`) just points to that memory location 1234. let's say you lost the card. the bank sends you *a new card*, but still pointing to memory location 1234 (the same bank account) this is like passing reference. but if you copy your bank account to memory 5678, you now have 2 accounts, so the *value* is copied.

Answer (score 4):

First, understand that in **C#** there are two fundamental types: **Value Types** and **Reference Types**.

Furthermore, each of those types can be passed to a method **By Value** or **By Reference**. (So, that means there are actually **four ways** to pass a parameter to a method.)

And regardless of how you pass a Reference Type (By Value or by Reference), you have the ability to change the value to which that reference points!

Now, with regard to your particular example, your parameter of question is of type `StringBuilder` which is a Reference Type. (`StringBuilder` is a **Class** and Classes are Reference Types.) And again, because you are passing a Reference Type to your method, you are able to change the value associated with that reference inside of that method.

Finally, note that you are passing your Reference Type parameter By Value. If instead you were to pass your Reference Type **By Reference** and then set it to `null`, you would actually destroy the value associated with the reference. (That would be the same as setting the parameter variable to `null` *outside* of the method.)

You can find a more more thorough and very readable explanation here: [C# Concepts: Value vs Reference Types](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Because StringBuilder is a `mutable` class and will passed by reference. Instead of string builder you use string it will be `Hello` because string is [`immutable`](http://codebetter.com/patricksmacchia/2008/01/13/immutable-types-understand-them-and-use-them/). Also for value types like `int`, `enum`, ... there isn't any change.

For simplicity, Value types are struct, enum, primitive types, ...
and reference types are classes, but As I mentioned there are some classes like string which are immutable and in fact, they will be passed by value.

Comment: Great! Thanks all for your quick and detailed answers. I was asked this question in a interview! and I was just validating my answer ;)

So to sum-up:

What is the default parameter passing method in C#... 
1. Pass by Value for value types, Pass by reference for reference types (Now I know its not :), but I had said this as answer)
2. Pass by Value for immutable types, Pass by reference for mutable types
3. Pass by Value for primitive types, Pass by reference for non-primitive types
4. Or is it still something else?

Comment: @Vishruth In fact your answer is good enough, and I think this isn't a good interview question, if you can understand difference between value type and reference types, and immutable and mutable objects, is good enough, except they have too many interview and takes it as paper exam.

Answer (score 3):

That parameter is still a pass-by-value but parameter variable `x` has a reference of the `StringBuilder` object.

The reference variable y has the reference of StringBuilder object

```
StringBuilder y = new StringBuilder();
```

and reference of StringBuilder object is copied to parameter x of Foo.

```
Foo (y);
```

Answer (score 1):

**StringBuilder** is a class, so it will be passed by reference.

read more: [Value vs reference types](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Compare the following. First with StringBuilder (reference type):

```
    public struct Tmd
    {
        public StringBuilder sb;
    }

    public void DoIt(Tmd a)
    {
        a.sb.Append(" World!");
    }

    public void Main()
    {
        Tmd a = new Tmd();
        a.sb = new StringBuilder();
        a.sb.Append("Hello");
        DoIt(a);
        Console.WriteLine(a.sb); // Hello World
    }
```

Here the struct is copied, as is the reference to the StringBuilder along with it, but the StringBuilder itself is not copied.

And now with a mutable struct (value type):

```
    public struct EvilMutable
    {
        public int i;
    }

    public struct Tmd
    {
        public EvilMutable em;
    }

    public void DoIt(Tmd a)
    {
        a.em.i += 1;
    }

    public void DoIt(EvilMutable em)
    {
        em.i += 1;
    }

    public void Main()
    {
        Tmd a = new Tmd();
        a.em.i += 5;
        Console.WriteLine(a.em.i); // 5
        DoIt(a);
        Console.WriteLine(a.em.i); // 5 (unchanged)
        DoIt(a.em);
        Console.WriteLine(a.em.i); // 5 (unchanged)
    }
```

In this case everything copied. However if we change this into a reference type:

```
    public class Tmd
    {
        public EvilMutable em;
    }
```

Then, we'll get this:

```
        Tmd a = new Tmd();
        a.em.i += 5;
        Console.WriteLine(a.em.i); // 5
        DoIt(a);
        Console.WriteLine(a.em.i); // 6
        DoIt(a.em);
        Console.WriteLine(a.em.i); // 6 (unchanged)
```